# swap two variables in verilog using XOR

Tags: verilog, fpga, xor, hdl

I have a line of data of 264 bits in memory buffer written using Verilog HDL.

```
buffer[2]=264'b000100000100001000000000001000000000000001000001000000000000000000000000000000000000100000010000010000100000000000100000000010000100001100000000000000000000000000000000000010000001000001000010000000000010000000000000010001010000000000000000000000000000000000001000;
```

I want to transfer 10 bits within the above raw from `buffer[2][147:138]` bits to `buffer[2][59:50]`, then transfer `buffer[2][235:226]` bits into `buffer[2][147:138]`

I try to do this using XOR but it dose not work

```
buffer[2][59:50]=buffer[2][59:50]^buffer[2][147:138];
buffer[2][147:138]=buffer[2][59:50]^buffer[2][147:138];
buffer[2][59:50]=buffer[2][59:50]^buffer[2][147:138];

buffer[2][235:226]=buffer[2][235:226]^buffer[2][147:138];
buffer[2][147:138]=buffer[2][235:226]^buffer[2][147:138];
buffer[2][235:226]=buffer[2][235:226]^buffer[2][147:138];
```

How can I do this without using non-blocking assignment ?

Comment: I think from hardware prospoective, this operation can't be done through combinational logic only and hence non-blocking assignment will be necessary.

Comment: Verilog is a Hardware Design Language (HDL), not an typical programming like Python or C, so when you design in Verilog, imagine the hardware circuit you describe.  The expressions, like `buffer[2][235:226]=buffer[2][235:226]^buffer[2][147:138];`, describes a combinatorial loop, which typically is not what to want to make in hardware.

Comment: @KaranShah i do't want to use non-blocking assignment , because there will be mix of blocking and non-blocking assignment in the module.

Comment: Think from.hardware. If you want to have sequential logic, then go for nonblocking, if combinational, then go for blocking assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can swap with concatenations, no xor required:

```
{buffer[2][147:138],buffer[2][59:50]} = {buffer[2][59:50],buffer[2][147:138]};

{buffer[2][235:226],buffer[2][147:138] = {buffer[2][147:138],buffer[2][235:226]};
```

Your title says *swap*, but your description says *transfer*. To transfer you can can still use the same approach:

```
{buffer[2][147:138],buffer[2][59:50]} = {buffer[2][235:226],buffer[2][147:138]}

// Or you can do this, beware order matters
buffer[2][59:50] = buffer[2][147:138];
buffer[2][147:138] = buffer[2][235:226];
```

Be careful where you do this in an `always` block. It can create a combinational feedback loop after synthesized if done incorrectly. The bits must first be assigned by a determinate value (ideally a flop) before doing the swap.

Comment: i want to transfer, when i did this :

`buffer[2][59:50] = buffer[2][147:138];`
`buffer[2][147:138] = buffer[2][235:226];`

the value of buffer[2][235:226] is transferred into buffer[2][59:50] 
which it is like delete buffer[2][147:138] and wire 
buffer[2][235:226] and  buffer[2][59:50] ,,,,,,,
this operation is done within always block

Comment: Concatenations will work for the _rotation_ behavior you need. `{buffer[2][59:50], buffer[2][147:138], buffer[2][235:226]} = {buffer[2][147:138], buffer[2][235:226], buffer[2][59:50]}`. However, if `buffer` is assigned on a clock edge (not purely combinational) then you should split the conbinational logic (`always @*`) and sequential logic (`always @(posedge clk)`). The sequential logic becomes an simple assignment `buffer[2] <= next_buffer[2];` The conbinational defaults to the flopped value (`next_buffer[2] = buffer[2]`) then can be modified for swap/transfer/rotation or other changes.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a new variable to hold the new, rearranged, array. This should not generate any logic, you are just rearranging wires.

```
reg [263:0] reArrBuffer [0:2];

assign reArrBuffer = 
              '{buffer[0],
                buffer[1],
                {buffer[2][263:148], buffer[2][235:226], buffer[2][137:60], buffer[2][147:138], buffer[2][49:0]}
               };
```

Note: You need `'` in front of the first `{` to create an assignment pattern for an unpacked array. It can be removed if `buffer` and `reArrBuffer` is packed.

Comment: FYI: `'{}` is for SystemVerilog (IEEE1800), not Verilog (IEEE1364)